# Group By Func LinQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following classes in C#:

```
public class Statistics {
    public SellerModel Seller {get; set;}
    public ClientModel Client {get; set;}
    public ProductModel Product {get; set;}
    public int Total1 {get; set;}
    public int Total2 {get; set;}
}
public class SellerModel {
    public int SellerId {get; set;}
    public string SellerName {get; set;}
}
public class ClientModel {
    public int ClientId {get; set;}
    public string ClientName {get; set;}
}
public class ProductModel {
    public int ProductId {get; set;}
    public string ProductName {get; set;}
}
```

I'm bringing an online query of statistics, but according to the user, I have to group by "Client and Seller" or "Product and Seller", and then it would be easy to make a decision and write twice the query in a personalized way, but not It is sustainable in time because here I give as an example just two ways to group, but in what I do, there are twelve classes that I should group together with a seller, and I would like to make a general method, which will send some parameters and it can be grouped according to what I send it.

I have already done something like this:

```
public IEnumerable<Statistic> GetStatistic(EnumStatistic enumStatistic) {
    //Consult everything I need without grouping
    var query = QueryStatistic();
    // Switch Decision Statistic
    IEnumerable<Statistic> model = null;
    switch (enumStatistic) {
        case EnumStatistic.Client {
            model = QueryStatisticGroup(query, x => x.Client, x => null);
            break;
        }
        case EnumStatistic.Product {
            model = QueryStatisticGroup(query, x => null, x => x.Product);
            break;
        }
    }
    return model;
}
private IEnumerable<Statistic> QueryStatisticGroup(
    IEnumerable<Statistic> query, 
    Func<Statistic, ClientModel> getClient,
    Func<Statistic, ProductModel> getProduct)
{
    var model = 
        from q in query
        group q by new
        {
            Product = getProduct(q),
            Client = getClient(q),
            Seller = q.Seller,
        } into g
        select new Statistic
        {
            Client = g.Key.Client,
            Product = g.Key.Product,
            Seller = g.Key.Seller,
            Total1 = g.Sum(x => x.q.Total1),
            Total2 = g.Sum(x => x.q.Total2),
         };
    return model;
}
```

There are two problems, it does not group by class because if it only groups by seller, the results are the same without grouping by any, and if I leave it as it is, it does not group either but the object is instantiated to "null", then, not really I know what to do.

I have tried in many ways, and I could not. The only way to group, but only by seller is placing it like this:

```
    group q by new
    {
        SellerId = q.Seller.SellerId,
        SellerName = q.Seller.SellerName
    } into g
```

But that seems impractical to me or sustainable in time.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: If this is in memory and not EF then you'll need to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` to be able to group on the values of your models instead of the references.  Also if the id is unique you could just group on that.

Comment: Yes, overwriting the equals and hashcode methods worked, I had to do it in all classes. Is there any way to send in an argument to all the objects for which I am going to group? or should always be of an argument. Is that I have 12 possible objects to group.